# Is there a way to know if a spring/water has sulfur?

Tags: southeast-asia, hygiene

Is there a quick way or a cheap test (like some kind of strip which would change its color if sulfur is present) to know if the water in a spring has sulfur content in it ?

Specifically, I am looking at making sure there is no sulfur in any of the springs that I may encounter while travelling in South Eastern Asia (Bangladesh, West Bengal(India)).

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://www.amazon.com/Analytical-Determination-Sulphites-Sulphur-Dioxide/dp/B008AZC74E ?

Comment: @Dirty-flow Yes, that's an option. Though I dont understand the difference between Sulphites and Sulphur Dioxide, I will google on it

Comment: This is quite specialistic question and I think you should ask on Chemistry.SE.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test to be sure that there is not *too much* sulfur could be done simply by smelling (sulfured hot springs typically have smell close to rotten eggs).

Though, such a smell could be indicative of sulfur somewhere else (not in the water), and too small concentrations of sulfur in water could smell nothing as well.

Comment: This isn't really a solution for somebody who is allergic to Sulfur, right ?

Comment: Certainly not, I agree, but it is not specified in the question that one is allergic to sulphur. :)